# Spark Dataframe Nested Case When Statement

Tags: sql, apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql

I need to implement the below SQL logic in Spark `DataFrame`

```sql
SELECT KEY,
    CASE WHEN tc in ('a','b') THEN 'Y'
         WHEN tc in ('a') AND amt > 0 THEN 'N'
         ELSE NULL END REASON,
FROM dataset1;
```

My input `DataFrame` is as below:

```scala
val dataset1 = Seq((66, "a", "4"), (67, "a", "0"), (70, "b", "4"), (71, "d", "4")).toDF("KEY", "tc", "amt")

dataset1.show()
```

```
+---+---+---+
|KEY| tc|amt|
+---+---+---+
| 66|  a|  4|
| 67|  a|  0|
| 70|  b|  4|
| 71|  d|  4|
+---+---+---+
```

I have implement the nested case when statement as:

```scala
dataset1.withColumn("REASON", when(col("tc").isin("a", "b"), "Y")
  .otherwise(when(col("tc").equalTo("a") && col("amt").geq(0), "N")
    .otherwise(null))).show()
```

```
+---+---+---+------+
|KEY| tc|amt|REASON|
+---+---+---+------+
| 66|  a|  4|     Y|
| 67|  a|  0|     Y|
| 70|  b|  4|     Y|
| 71|  d|  4|  null|
+---+---+---+------+
```

Readability of the above logic with "otherwise" statement is little messy if the nested when statements goes further.

Is there any better way of implementing nested case when statements in Spark `DataFrames`?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

There is no nesting here, therefore there is no need for `otherwise`. All you need is chained `when`:

```scala
import spark.implicits._

when($"tc" isin ("a", "b"), "Y")
  .when($"tc" === "a" && $"amt" >= 0, "N")
```

`ELSE NULL` is implicit so you can omit it completely.

Pattern you use, is more more applicable for `folding` over a data structure:

```scala
val cases = Seq(
  ($"tc" isin ("a", "b"), "Y"),
  ($"tc" === "a" && $"amt" >= 0, "N")
)
```

where `when` - `otherwise` naturally follows recursion pattern and `null` provides the base case.

```scala
cases.foldLeft(lit(null)) {
  case (acc, (expr, value)) => when(expr, value).otherwise(acc)
}
```

Please note, that it is impossible to reach "N" outcome, with this chain of conditions. If `tc` is equal to "a" it will be captured by the first clause. If it is not, it will fail to satisfy both predicates and default to `NULL`. You should rather:

```scala
when($"tc" === "a" && $"amt" >= 0, "N")
 .when($"tc" isin ("a", "b"), "Y")
```

Answer (score 3):

For more complex logic, I prefer to use UDFs for better readability:

```
val selectCase = udf((tc: String, amt: String) =>
  if (Seq("a", "b").contains(tc)) "Y"
  else if (tc == "a" && amt.toInt <= 0) "N"
  else null
)


dataset1.withColumn("REASON", selectCase(col("tc"), col("amt")))
  .show
```

Comment: but it should be mentioned that udfs might have performance penalty as they might prevent filters pushdown. this is not always the case of course, but it's a good practice to stick to spark's native functions as much as possible.

Comment: never use UDFs as much as possible unless needed. this can negatively affect performance.

Answer (score 1):

you can simply use selectExpr on your dataset

```
dataset1.selectExpr("*", "CASE WHEN tc in ('a') AND amt > 0 THEN 'N' WHEN tc in ('a','b') THEN 'Y' ELSE NULL END
REASON").show()

+---+---+---+------+
|KEY| tc|amt|REASON|
+---+---+---+------+
| 66|  a|  4|     N|
| 67|  a|  0|     Y|
| 70|  b|  4|     Y|
| 71|  d|  4|  null|
+---+---+---+------+
```

Second condition should be place before first one, as first condition is more generic one.

> WHEN tc in ('a') AND amt > 0 THEN 'N'

Comment: This option works really well for me. I have a situation where there is lots of nested conditions in my pyspark code and it was becoming difficult to read. Using this approach makes my code much more readable.